# Aislar Qwidget de una funcion

Tags: python, python-3.x

¿Como puedo aislar el widget `self.combo_login`, de las funciones `mousePressEvent` y `mouseMoveEvent`?,

Esto con la finalidad de que cuando el mouse este clickeando sobre el `self.combo_login` no se ejecuten esas funciones:

codigo:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication
from PyQt5 import uic, QtCore, Qt
from Inicio import Inicio
from Firebase_load import *
from Registro import Image
from add_users import Usuarios
from es import user_name_1

class Principal(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        uic.loadUi("Login.ui",self)
        self._Inicio = Inicio()
        self.registro = Image()
        self.add = Usuarios()


        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground,True)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_NoSystemBackground,False)

        self.closed.clicked.connect(lambda:self.close())
        self.mostrar_hora()

        self.combo_login ############### Widget

        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        self.timer.setInterval(1000)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.mostrar_hora)
        self.timer.start()

    def mostrar_hora(self):
        self.hora.setText(QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime().toString("hh:mm:ss AP"))



class Dato(Principal):
    def __init__(self):
        Principal.__init__(self)
        self.b_login.clicked.connect(self.validate_User)

    def validate_User(self):

        user = self.l_usuario.text()

        if user == '':
            self.l_status.setText('No se ingreso un usuario')
        else:
            ref = db.reference("/usuarios/")
            res = ref.get()

            for key in res.items():
                if key[0] == user:
                    self.validate_password(user)
    def validate_password(self,user):
        password  = self.l_password.text()

        refp = db.reference("/usuarios/"+user)
        res = refp.get()

        for key in res.items():
            if key[0] == 'password':
                if key[1] == password:
                    self.other()
                    self.l_status.setText("login")
                    pass
                else:
                    self.l_password.setText('')
                    self.l_status.setText("Invalidate Password")
            elif key[0] == 'permisos':
                self.registro.acces = int(key[1])
                self.add.acces = int(key[1])



    def other(self):

        self.close()
        user_name_1(self.l_usuario.text())
        self._Inicio.user_online_on(self.l_usuario.text(),self.combo_login.currentText())
        self._Inicio.user.setText(self.l_usuario.text())
        self._Inicio.show()

    def mousePressEvent(self,event):
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            self.dragPosition = event.globalPos() - self.frameGeometry().topLeft()
            event.accept()
    def mouseMoveEvent(self,event):
        if event.buttons() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            self.move(event.globalPos()-self.dragPosition)
            event.accept()

app = QApplication([])
p = Dato()
p.show()
app.exec_()
```

Login.ui

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <ui version="4.0">
     <class>MainWindow</class>
     <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>0</x>
        <y>0</y>
        <width>351</width>
        <height>551</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <property name="windowTitle">
       <string>MainWindow</string>
      </property>
      <property name="windowIcon">
       <iconset>
        <normaloff>icono.ico</normaloff>icono.ico</iconset>
      </property>
      <property name="styleSheet">
       <string notr="true">background:qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), stop:1 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));</string>
      </property>
      <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
       <property name="styleSheet">
        <string notr="true">background:qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), stop:1 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));</string>
       </property>
       <widget class="QFrame" name="frame">
        <property name="geometry">
         <rect>
          <x>0</x>
          <y>90</y>
          <width>351</width>
          <height>461</height>
         </rect>
        </property>
        <property name="styleSheet">
         <string notr="true">background:qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0.494249, y1:0, x2:0.472, y2:1, stop:0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 202), stop:1 rgba(51, 51, 51, 218));</string>
        </property>
        <property name="frameShape">
         <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
        </property>
        <property name="frameShadow">
         <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
        </property>
        <widget class="QLabel" name="login">
         <property name="geometry">
          <rect>
           <x>10</x>
           <y>180</y>
           <width>161</width>
           <height>31</height>
          </rect>
         </property>
         <property name="font">
          <font>
           <pointsize>14</pointsize>
          </font>
         </property>
         <property name="styleSheet">
          <string notr="true">QLabel#login{
    background:None;
    color:white;
    }</string>
         </property>
         <property name="text">
          <string>Login</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
        <widget class="QLabel" name="icono_usuario">
         <property name="geometry">
          <rect>
           <x>10</x>
           <y>230</y>
           <width>32</width>
           <height>32</height>
          </rect>
         </property>
         <property name="styleSheet">
          <string notr="true">QLabel#icono_usuario{
    background:#7A7B7F;
    border:0px;
    background-image:url(Images/usuario.png)
    }</string>
         </property>
         <property name="text">
          <string/>
         </property>
         <property name="pixmap">
          <pixmap>new/Imagenes/usuario.png</pixmap>
         </property>
         <property name="alignment">
          <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
         </property>
        </widget>
        <widget class="QLabel" name="icono_contrasena">
         <property name="geometry">
          <rect>
           <x>10</x>
           <y>280</y>
           <width>32</width>
           <height>32</height>
          </rect>
         </property>
         <property name="styleSheet">
          <string notr="true">QLabel#icono_contrasena{
    background:#7A7B7F;
    border :0px;
    background-image:url(Images/pss.png);
    background-repeat:none;
    background-position:center;
    }</string>
         </property>
         <property name="text">
          <string/>
         </property>
         <property name="pixmap">
          <pixmap>new/Imagenes/pss.png</pixmap>
         </property>
         <property name="scaledContents">
          <bool>false</bool>
         </property>
         <property name="alignment">
          <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
         </property>
        </widget>
        <widget class="QLineEdit" name="l_password">
         <property name="geometry">
          <rect>
           <x>42</x>
           <y>280</y>
           <width>291</width>
           <height>32</height>
          </rect>
         </property>
         <property name="font">
          <font>
           <pointsize>10</pointsize>
          </font>
         </property>
         <property name="styleSheet">
          <string notr="true">QLineEdit#l_password{
    border:0px;
    background:qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0.494249, y1:0, x2:0.472, y2:1, stop:0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 183), stop:1 rgba(157, 157, 157, 94));
    color:white;
    }</string>
         </property>
         <property name="inputMethodHints">
          <set>Qt::ImhHiddenText|Qt::ImhNoAutoUppercase|Qt::ImhNoPredictiveText|Qt::ImhSensitiveData</set>
         </property>
         <property name="text">
          <string/>
         </property>
         <property name="echoMode">
          <enum>QLineEdit::Password</enum>
         </property>
        </widget>
        <widget class="QLineEdit" name="l_usuario">
         <property name="geometry">
          <rect>
           <x>42</x>
           <y>230</y>
           <width>291</width>
           <height>32</height>
          </rect>
         </property>
         <property name="font">
          <font>
           <pointsize>10</pointsize>
          </font>
         </property>
         <property name="styleSheet">
          <string notr="true">QLineEdit#l_usuario{
    border:0px;
    background:qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0.494249, y1:0, x2:0.472, y2:1, stop:0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 183), stop:1 rgba(157, 157, 157, 94));
    color:white;
    }</string>
         </property>
         <property name="inputMask">
          <string/>
         </property>
         <property name="text">
          <string/>
         </property>
         <property name="cursorPosition">
          <number>0</number>
         </property>
         <property name="placeholderText">
          <string/>
         </property>
        </widget>
        <widget class="QPushButton" name="b_login">
         <property name="geometry">
          <rect>
           <x>240</x>
           <y>380</y>
           <width>91</width>
           <height>31</height>
          </rect>
         </property>
         <property name="font">
          <font>
           <pointsize>9</pointsize>
           <weight>50</weight>
           <bold>false</bold>
          </font>
         </property>
         <property name="styleSheet">
          <string notr="true">QPushButton#b_login{
    border:0px;
    background:qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0.494249, y1:0, x2:0.472, y2:1, stop:0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 255), stop:1 rgba(234, 234, 234, 255));
    }


    }
    QPushButton#b_login:hover{
    border:0px;
    background:qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0.494249, y1:0, x2:0.472, y2:1, stop:0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 255), stop:1 rgba(200, 200, 200, 255));

    }
    QPushButton#b_login:pressed{
    border:0px;
    background:qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0.494249, y1:0, x2:0.472, y2:1, stop:0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 255), stop:1 rgba(234, 234, 234, 255));
    border-bottom:2px solid grey;</string>
         </property>
         <property name="text">
          <string>Login</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
        <widget class="QPushButton" name="closed">
         <property name="geometry">
          <rect>
           <x>320</x>
           <y>0</y>
           <width>31</width>
           <height>23</height>
          </rect>
         </property>
         <property name="font">
          <font>
           <pointsize>9</pointsize>
           <weight>75</weight>
           <bold>true</bold>
          </font>
         </property>
         <property name="styleSheet">
          <string notr="true">QPushButton#closed{
    background:None;
    border:0px;
    color:lightgrey;
    }
    QPushButton#closed:hover{
    color:#D8211D;
    }</string>
         </property>
         <property name="text">
          <string>X</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
        <widget class="QLabel" name="hora">
         <property name="geometry">
          <rect>
           <x>0</x>
           <y>440</y>
           <width>101</width>
           <height>20</height>
          </rect>
         </property>
         <property name="font">
          <font>
           <pointsize>10</pointsize>
          </font>
         </property>
         <property name="styleSheet">
          <string notr="true">QLabel#hora{
    background:None;
    color:white;
    }</string>
         </property>
         <property name="text">
          <string/>
         </property>
         <property name="alignment">
          <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
         </property>
        </widget>
        <widget class="QLabel" name="l_status">
         <property name="geometry">
          <rect>
           <x>60</x>
           <y>330</y>
           <width>231</width>
           <height>21</height>
          </rect>
         </property>
         <property name="styleSheet">
          <string notr="true">QLabel#l_status{
    background:None;
    color:white;
    }</string>
         </property>
         <property name="text">
          <string/>
         </property>
         <property name="alignment">
          <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
         </property>
        </widget>
        <widget class="QComboBox" name="combo_login">
         <property name="enabled">
          <bool>true</bool>
         </property>
         <property name="geometry">
          <rect>
           <x>150</x>
           <y>360</y>
           <width>50</width>
           <height>17</height>
          </rect>
         </property>
         <property name="styleSheet">
          <string notr="true">QComboBox#combo_login{
    background:qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), stop:1 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
    border:0px;
    color:white;
    border-bottom: 1px solid lightblue;
    }


    QComboBox QAbstractItemView
    {
        border: 2px solid darkgray;
        background:grey;
        color: black;
        selection-background-color: QLinearGradient( x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1, stop: 0 #111, stop: 1 #333);
    }
    QComboBox#combo_login::drop-down
    {
         subcontrol-origin: padding;
         subcontrol-position: top right;
         width: 15px;
         color: white;
         border-left-width: 0px;
         border-left-color: darkgray;
         border-left-style: solid; /* just a single line */
         border-top-right-radius: 3px; /* same radius as the QComboBox */
         border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
         padding-left: 10px;
     }</string>
         </property>
         <item>
          <property name="text">
           <string>exe1</string>
          </property>
         </item>
         <item>
          <property name="text">
           <string>exe2</string>
          </property>
         </item>
         <item>
          <property name="text">
           <string>exe3</string>
          </property>
         </item>
        </widget>
       </widget>
       <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
        <property name="geometry">
         <rect>
          <x>90</x>
          <y>10</y>
          <width>181</width>
          <height>171</height>
         </rect>
        </property>
        <property name="styleSheet">
         <string notr="true">background:url(Images/Login.png);
    background-repeat:none;
    background-position:center;</string>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string/>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </widget>
     </widget>
     <resources/>
     <connections/>
    </ui>
```

Intente definir la funcion eventFilter en la clase Dato

```
def eventFilter(self,obj,event):
     if obj != self.combo_login:
         objeto = True
     return objeto
```

esto con la finalidad de agregar una condicion en el evento mousePressEvent, donde si el objeto = True entonces se ejecutara la funcion si no no lo hiciera perono funciono

Comment: ¿su código es un [mcve]?

Comment: @eyllanesc, espero puedas ayudarme :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No puedo testearlo ahora mismo, pero creo recordar que los eventos tienen un target. Al menos, es así si los capturas mediante `eventFilter`.

```
def eventFilter(self, target, event):
    """Configure special events."""
    if event.type() == QEvent.MouseButtonPress:
        if not target == self.combo_login: # Aqui dejamos fuera el combo
            if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton: # Ahora quizás no necesites esta linea
                self.dragPosition = event.globalPos() - self.frameGeometry().topLeft()
            event.accept()
    elif event.type() == QEvent.MouseMove:
        if not target == self.combo_login: # Aqui dejamos fuera el combo
            if event.buttons() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton: # Ahora quizás no necesites esta linea
                self.move(event.globalPos()-self.dragPosition)
                event.accept()
    return False
```

Aunque, para capturar eventos de esta manera, se debe instalar manualmente un filtro de eventos a los widgets que queremos capturar. Para ello, hazlo en el init de tu clase.

```
class Principal(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        self.installEventFilter(self)
        # self.combo_login.installEventFilter(self) # Ejemplo por si solo quieres lanzar un evento en un widget diferente.
```

Comment: no me funciona, no puedo mover mi ventana principal

Comment: Has probado eliminando las 2 lineas que he comentado con "quizas..."? Y has instalado el filtro de eventos en init? **EDIT:** Tienes razón, tenía yo un fallo, había copiado y pegado el código y ponía MouseButtonPress en ambos sitios, en lugar de MouseMove que es el que tú usabas para mover la ventana. Espero que eso lo arregle, porque hasta mañana no podré testearlo en mi maquina de trabajo.

Comment: parece que mi solucion no funciono, veras el problema que tengo es que queria aislar el self.combo de esos eventos por que si doy click en el combobox y llego a mover el mouse me lanza el siguiente error:      Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\Angel\Videos\Test\Login.py", line 99, in eventFilter
     self.move(event.globalPos()-self.dragPosition)
 AttributeError: 'Dato' object has no attribute 'dragPosition'

Comment: Si, ya entiendo el problema. `dragPosition` se asigna al clickear, pero se utiliza al mover. Al ser dos eventos diferentes, la variable no va de un sitio a otro. Creo que se puede hacer de las dos maneras, con tu planteamiento o con el mio. Sin embargo, en caso de hacerlo en eventFilter habría que programarlo todo todo en un solo evento o guardar las variables a nivel de clase (en el init). Es más complicado de lo que inicialmente parecía.

Comment: puedes ayudarme llevo un buen rato tratando de solucionar este error y ya me desespere